# What do you do when you encounter ENOBUFS/ENOMEM while calling read(2)?

Tags: linux, posix

If I receive `ENOBUFS` or `ENOMEM` during a call to *read(2)*, is it possible that the kernel may free up resources and a future call will succeed? Or, do I treat the error as fatal, and begin a teardown process?

Comment: I don't know what the officially recommended behavior is, but in my programming I ran across this problem and found that the ENOBUFS error was transient; i.e. if I called read() again it would then succeed.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit at a loss to see what possible use may come from retrying.

If you got back ENOMEM on a read, it means the kernel is in serious trouble. Yes, it is possible that retrying might work, but it is also possible it will not. If it will not, how long is appropriate to wait before retrying? If you retry immediately, what's to prevent you from adding another process doing 100% CPU bound loop?

Personally, if I got such an error from a read for which I know how to handle errors, I'd handle the error as usual. If it is a situation where I positively need the read to succeed, then I'd fail the program. If this program is mission critical, you will need to run it inside a watchdog that restarts it anyway.

On that note, please bear in mind that if the kernel returned ENOMEM, there is a non-negligible probability that the OOM killer will send SIGKILL to someone. Experience has shown that someone will likely be your process. That is just one more reason to just exit, and handle that exit with a watchdog monitoring the process (bear in mind, however, that the watchdog might also get a SIGKILL if the OOM killer was triggered).

The situation with ENOBUFS isn't much different. The "how long to delay" and infinite loop considerations are still there. OOM killer is less likely under such considerations, but relying on the watchdog is still the correct path, IMHO.

The core issue here is that there are no specific cases in which `read(2)` *should* return any of those errors. If a condition arises that results in those errors, it is just as legitimate for the driver to return `EIO`.

As such, and unless OP knows of a specific use case his code is built to handle, these errors really should be handled the same way.

One last not regarding the OOM killer. People sometimes think of it as something that will save them from hanging the entire system. That is not really the case. The OOM killer **randomly** kills a process. It is true that the more pages the process has, the more likely it is that it be the one being killed. I strongly suggest no relying on that fact, however.

I have seen cases where physical memory was exhausted, where the OOM killer killed a process that used very little memory, taking some time to get to the main culprit. I've seen cases that the memory exhaustion was in the kernel address space, and the user space processes being killed were completely random.

As I've said above, OOM killer might kill your watchdog process, leaving your main hogger running. Do not rely on it to fix your code path.

Comment: What about `ENOBUFS`? Your answer seems to be at odds with the comment on the question. I'm writing an application that needs to be as reliable as possible, I don't want to just quit because the pressure is on, I only want to terminate if it's absolutely the only course of action. I'm writing a network service, waiting around is not so much of an issue for me. As you mention, I'd rather wait for `SIGKILL` to actually tear things down since that seems to be the authority on whether my process should exist or not, not some spurious read error.

Comment: @dcow, did you actually ever get those errors? The man page for "read" doesn't list them as possible return codes, so I'm guessing you'd only ever get them for specific FS drivers or custom character devices.

Comment: @dcow, edited answer to elaborate on your follow on questions.